# java multipart POST library

Tags: java, post, multipart

Is there a multipart POST library out there that achieve the same effect of doing a POST from a html form? for example - upload a file programmingly in Java versus upload the file using a html form. And on the server side, it just blindly expect the request from client side to be a multipart POST request and parse out the data as appropriate.

Has anyone tried this?

specifically, I am trying to see if I can simulate the following with Java

The user creates a blob by submitting an HTML form that includes one or more file input fields. Your app sets **blobstoreService.createUploadUrl()** as the destination (action) of this form, passing the function a URL path of a handler in your app. When the user submits the form, the user's browser uploads the specified files directly to the Blobstore. The Blobstore rewrites the user's request and stores the uploaded file data, replacing the uploaded file data with one or more corresponding blob keys, then passes the rewritten request to the handler at the URL path you provided to blobstoreService.createUploadUrl(). This handler can do additional processing based on the blob key. Finally, the handler must return a headers-only, redirect response (301, 302, or 303), typically a browser redirect to another page indicating the status of the blob upload.

Set **blobstoreService.createUploadUrl** as the form action, passing the application path to load when the POST of the form is completed.

```
<body>
    <form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="myFile">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Note that this is how the upload form would look if it were created as a JSP.
The form must include a file upload field, and the form's enctype must be set to multipart/form-data. When the user submits the form, the POST is handled by the Blobstore API, which creates the blob. The API also creates an info record for the blob and stores the record in the datastore, and passes the rewritten request to your app on the given path as a blob key.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a library; this is possible with the stock Java classes ([example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html)).

On the server side you will implement a Java Servlet solution that makes parsing HTTP request parameters very simple.

Comment: thanks, but what if the form to simulate is something like the following? <body>
    <form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="myFile">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java

Answer (score 0):

A complete and de facto standard HTTP implementation (included for example in the Android platform) you will find at [Apache httpcomponent](http://hc.apache.org/)