# Apache HttpClient making multipart POST to Spring @Controller class

Tags: spring, file-upload, httpclient, multipart, multipartform-data

It seems like there are several posts such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java) asking how to use Apache Commons HTTPClient libraries in Java to do a POST to a Servlet.  However, it seems like I'm having some problems doing the same thing with a annotated Spring controller method.  I've tried a few things but gotten HTTP 401 Bad Request responses from the server.  Any examples of doing this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Code I am trying to use:

```
//Server Side (Java)
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createDocument(@RequestParam("userId") String userId,
                           @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // Do some stuff                            
}

//Client Side (Groovy)
    void processJob(InputStream stream, String remoteAddress) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient()
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1)
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://someurl/rest/create")

    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
    InputStreamBody uploadFilePart = new InputStreamBody(stream, 'application/octet-stream', 'test.file')
    mpEntity.addPart('file', uploadFilePart)
    mpEntity.addPart('userId', new StringBody('testUser'))
    httppost.setEntity(mpEntity)

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    println(response.statusLine)
}
```

Still getting 400 Bad Request in the response from the server.

Comment: can you show code/configuration that you have tried?

Comment: Tried to give basic code from client and server without too many external dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question when it shows incompetence, but it turns out the code was fine, this particular controller did not have a CommonsMultipartResolver defined in its servlet-context.xml file (multiple DispatcherServlets...long story :()

Here's what I added to make it work:

```
<!-- ========================= Resolver DEFINITIONS ========================= -->
<bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example from [the Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-forms):

```
@Controller
public class FileUpoadController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            // store the bytes somewhere
           return "redirect:uploadSuccess";
       } else {
           return "redirect:uploadFailure";
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: James, that is a working example from the Spring controller side, I'm trying to figure out the client side using HTTPClient, any ideas?

Comment: On the client side, you can use Spring's [RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-client-access) to consume RESTful Web services.  I'm still trying to dig up a more general HTTP client example.

Comment: [Here](http://www.earldouglas.com/a-secure-restful-web-service) I made a *very* rudimentary HTTP client in the `EmployeeControllerTest.get` method.  Hopefully it can point you in the right direction.