# Passing image as a parameter to a php script from a java program

Tags: java, php, web, image-uploading

I have a java program at the client side from which I need to send an image to upload to the server running the php script.
Can anyone please suggest ways of doing this?

Comment: just make a POST HTTP request. e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pr

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to send an HTTP POST request with the image data included as the body.

As for a java solution, here's a similar post:

[How to upload binary data using POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055278/how-to-upload-binary-data-using-post)