# JAX RS file upload

Tags: file-upload, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to set up file upload example using JAX RS. I could set up the project when the client is a JSP page and there are no issues. But i would like to have the client as a java class which sends post request to the service. My server side code is as shown below.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("/file")
public class UploadFileService {

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    String uploadedFileLocation = "d://uploaded/"
            + fileDetail.getFileName();


    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}


private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        String uploadedFileLocation) {

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

The client as a JSP page is as shown below.

```xml
<html>
<body>
<h1>File Upload with Jersey</h1>

<form action="http://localhost:9090/RESTfulExample/rest/file/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <p>
    Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="45" />
   </p>

   <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please help me with a class file as a client?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache's httpclient and httpmime to accomplish this:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class Uploader {

  public void uploadFile(String endpoint, File file) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(endpoint);
    FileBody uploadFilePart = new FileBody(file);
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    reqEntity.addPart("file", uploadFilePart);
    httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    //Check response for success
  }

}
```

Which works with your sample server code. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java), as well.

Comment: hi, i tried using httpclient but i am getting "HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request".

Comment: endpoint value is my post url -http://localhost:9090/RESTfulExample/rest/file/upload

Comment: Odd - these exact classes in this post work for me locally. Does the log from your Jersey server contain a stack trace that might indicate the reason for the 404 response?

Comment: I tried the same thing using spring and it worked perfectly after i set maxUploadSize in servlet.xml(The problem was due to file size i guess). In jersey is there a way we can set maxUploadSize somewhere?

Comment: This should be a property of the container running Jersey.

Comment: I am using tomcat. By defautl post size is 2MB. I changed it to infinite but still same issue. I guess i'll stick to spring only :)

Comment: Did this client class meet your needs?

Comment: Hi, yes this client worked but the problem was with web service i guess

Comment: Hi, can i set proxy in jersey client?