# Upload a file using a PUT request in Java with upload progress

Tags: java, http, http-put

I'm trying to do something really simple, but so far I've been unsuccessful in trying various methods of making it happen. I've tried uploading to a URL using a simple `java.io.Socket`, using a `java.io.HttpURLConnection`, and last using a `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient`, but I've failed to make it happen each time.

I need to make a request like this:

```
PUT http://1.2.3.4:8080/upload?ticket_id=abcdef124567890 HTTP/1.1
Host: 1.2.3.4:8080
Content-Length: 339108
Content-Type: video/mp4

\0abc\32af ... etc.
```

I need to write the bytes of a file (presumably from a `FileInputStream`) to the main request body, containing the video bytes.

I basically have two requirements:

1. I must upload the file using a PUT request to a given server.
2. I must be able to watch the progress of the upload as it's happening.

How can I make this happen in Java?

---

#### EDIT

Here's my attempt at doing this using Apache's `HttpClient`:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
PutMethod httpMethod = new PutMethod(ticket.getEndpoint());
httpMethod.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
httpMethod.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(getStreamFile().length()));

final FileInputStream streamFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(getStreamFile());
final BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(streamFileInputStream);

httpMethod.setRequestEntity(new RequestEntity() {
    @Override public void writeRequest(OutputStream out) 
            throws IOException {
        byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[getBufferLength()];
        
        int bytesRead = 0;
        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        final int totalFileBytes = (int)getStreamFile().length();
        
        while ((bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(fileBuffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(fileBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            
            notifyListenersOnProgress((double)totalBytesRead / (double)totalFileBytes);
        }
    }
    
    @Override public boolean isRepeatable() {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override public String getContentType() {
        return "video/mp4";
    }
    
    @Override public long getContentLength() {
        return getStreamFile().length();
    }
});

final int responseCode = httpClient.executeMethod(httpMethod);

logger.debug("Server Response {}: {}", responseCode, 
        httpMethod.getResponseBodyAsString());
```

This fails with a `java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe` exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1 you will need to use [multipart request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java). The referred post describes it. For 2, use some [counting stream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html) wrapper as you send data. Counting stream may need to be hooked inside HttpClient.

More details can be provided if you add more specifics on what is not working for you.

Comment: Ok, updated my question. Do I still need a multipart request in a PUT request even though the server is expecting to read straight from the request body?

Comment: Broken pipe exception, probably means that server closed connection. It could have done it because some byte sequence was detected or for some other reason. Multipart protocol ensures that binary data goes through correctly, but obviously you have to send data in format understood by server. Do you control the server code?

Comment: Nope, it's a [Vimeo upload server](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload#streaming-step3) and accepts things according to that protocol. I'm following directions and it's failing for some reason.

Comment: May be they detect some problem with file. I does not seem to be a problem with your client.

Comment: I would contact their support (or post on their support forum).

Comment: On the other hand, you can try really small video file and see what happens.

Comment: It's a pretty small file altogether, only 1.4 mb.

Comment: By the way, did you get upload ticket that they require? Because your question shows their example ticket id.