# How to add headers and file to junit test of REST

Tags: java, junit

So here is my function:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response postMsg(@HeaderParam("FTP-Host") String Host, @HeaderParam("FTP-Port") String Port,
        @HeaderParam("FTP-User") String User, @HeaderParam("FTP-Password") String Password,
        @HeaderParam("FTP-Path") String Path, @FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream) {

    try {
        InformationHandler informationHandler = new InformationHandler(Path, Host, Port, User, Password);

        CountriesStructure worker = new CountriesStructure();
        worker.prepareCountriesStructure(inputStream, true, informationHandler);

    } catch (UsernameOrPasswordException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(401).entity("Status 401.").build();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(404).entity("Status 404.").build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(400).entity("Status 400.").build();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(500).entity("Status 500.").build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(500).entity("Status 500.").build();

    }
    return Response.status(200).entity("Success!").build();
}
```

And I want to make test in Junit. But I don't have idea how to add headers and file. Here is my test (it works):

```
@Test
public void firstTest()
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/JerseyWebApp/ftpaction/upload");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(request);
    assertThat(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED));
}
```

But how can I add here headers and file?
Header I think that I can do in that way: `request.addHeader(value, key);` or am I wrong?

And I have totally no idea how to add file to test :/

Comment: You can use HTTPClient API.

Comment: Headers are added via request.addHeader. In your test you create get request but this is a PUT handler so you should create put request to be able to send files. File can be sent using method described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546609/use-httpclient-post-to-submit-form-with-upload

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock Header object using Mockito or other frameworks

```
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
request.addHeader("x-real-ip","127.0.0.1");
```