# How to encode UTF-8 CloseableHttpClient request

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a simple POST:

```
String url = "https://mysite";
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().build()) {   
   URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url);
   HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(params);
   request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
   String encodedAuthorization = URLEncoder.encode(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

    request.addHeader("Authorization", encodedAuthorization);
   try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request)) {
```

I have to support UTF-8 encoding and encoding `UrlEncodedFormEntity` isn't enough, but it's not clear what **must** be done, following several options available

Using `uriBuilder.setCharset`:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uriBuilder.setCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).build());
```

Using `http.protocol.content-charset` parameter:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uriBuilder.setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8").build());
```

Or just adding [Content-Type"` header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220396/apache-httpclient-post-request-to-etools-ch-with-utf-8-chars-in-the-query):

```
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
```

Or use [request.getParams()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024268/how-to-encode-russian-text-in-post-request-using-apache-httpclient):

```
request.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
request.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8");
```

Or other obvious solution I overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly encode I move to use parameters in  `List<NameValuePair>` over `URIBuilder`

and then encode using

```
URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Method to encode a string value using `UTF-8` encoding scheme
private static String encodeValue(String value) {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex.getCause());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=";

    String query = "Hellö Wörld@Java";
    String encodedQuery = encodeValue(query); // Encoding a query string

    String completeUrl = baseUrl + encodedQuery;
    System.out.println(completeUrl);
}
```

}

## Output

https://www.google.com/search?q=Hell%C3%B6+W%C3%B6rld%40Java

I think this may be the solution.

You refer to above: https://www.urlencoder.io/java/

Comment: what's the connection to `CloseableHttpClient`?

Comment: I am not sure for this solution but you should consult: httpPost.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");

Comment: If the url you include is text, you can use the code above.