# Converting MultipartFile to java.io.File without copying to local machine

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-io, multipart

I have a Java Spring MVC web application. From client, through AngularJS, I am uploading a file and posting it to Controller as webservice.

In my Controller, I am gettinfg it as **MultipartFile** and I can copy it to local machine.

But I want to upload the file to **Amazone S3** bucket. So I have to convert it to **java.io.File**. Right now what I am doing is, I am copying it to local machine and then uploading to S3 using [**jets3t**](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/code-samples.html).

Here is my way of converting in controller

```
MultipartHttpServletRequest mRequest=(MultipartHttpServletRequest)request;

Iterator<String> itr=mRequest.getFileNames();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            MultipartFile mFile=mRequest.getFile(itr.next());
            String fileName=mFile.getOriginalFilename();

            fileLoc="/home/mydocs/my-uploads/"+date+"_"+fileName; //date is String form of current date.
```

Then I am using FIleCopyUtils of SpringFramework

```
File newFile = new File(fileLoc);

                  // if the directory does not exist, create it
                  if (!newFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
                    newFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();  
                  }
                FileCopyUtils.copy(mFile.getBytes(), newFile);
```

So it will create a new file in the local machine. That file I am uplaoding in S3

```
S3Object fileObject = new S3Object(newFile);

s3Service.putObject("myBucket", fileObject);
```

It creates file in my local system. I don't want to create.

**Without creating a file in local system, how to convert a *MultipartFIle* to *java.io.File*?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MultipartFile, by default, is already saved on your server as a file when user uploaded it.
From that point - you can do anything you want with this file.
There is a method that moves that temp file to any destination you want.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#transferTo(java.io.File)

But MultipartFile is just API, you can implement any other **MultipartResolver** 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartResolver.html

This API accepts input stream and you can do anything you want with it. Default implementation (usually commons-multipart) saves it to temp dir as a file.

But other problem stays here   - if S3 API accepts a file as a parameter - you cannot do anything with this - you need a real file. If you want to avoid creating files at all - create you own S3 API.

Comment: Only problem is creating the file in local machine. What I am doing now is, after uploading in amazon, I am deleting from my local machine.

Comment: What inspires that problem ? S3 java-API ? Or what ? Do you have ability to send input stream to S3 ?

Comment: This is incorrect in regard to S3 API accepting only file parameter, it accepts also InputStream

Answer (score 5):

The question is already more than one year old, so I'm not sure if the [jets35](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/code-samples.html#uploading) link provided by the OP had the following snippet at that time.

> If your data isn't a `File` or `String` you can use any **input stream** as a data source, but **you must manually set the Content-Length**.
>
> ```java
> // Create an object containing a greeting string as input stream data.
> String greeting = "Hello World!";
>
> S3Object helloWorldObject = new S3Object("HelloWorld2.txt");
>
> ByteArrayInputStream greetingIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(greeting.getBytes());
>
> helloWorldObject.setDataInputStream(greetingIS);
> helloWorldObject.setContentLength(
>     greeting.getBytes(Constants.DEFAULT_ENCODING).length);
> helloWorldObject.setContentType("text/plain");
>
> s3Service.putObject(testBucket, helloWorldObject);
> ```

It turns out you don't have to create a local file first. As @Boris suggests you can feed the `S3Object` with the `Data Input Stream`, `Content Type` and `Content Length` you'll get from [`MultipartFile.getInputStream()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getInputStream--), [`MultipartFile.getContentType()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getContentType--) and [`MultipartFile.getSize()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getSize--) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying it to your local machine, you can just do this and replace the file name with this:

```
File newFile = new File(multipartFile.getOriginalName());
```

This way, you don't have to have a local destination create your file

Answer (score -2):

if you are try to use in httpentity check my answer here

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68022695/7532946
```