# constructing a multipart form request in a adapter using MobileFirst version 6.3

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

i have a application from which i need to construct a multipart form in a HTTP adapter and send it to webservice using WL.Server.invokeHttp. is there a way by which i can achieve this?.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript adapters do not support multi-part.

You have two options:

1. In MFPF 6.3, [use Java in JavaScript adapters](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/server-side-development/using-java-adapters/)
2. Upgrade to MFPF 7.0, which now provides [*Java* adapters](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/java-adapter/)

You can then try to implement the following (or similar for your specific use case): [How can I make a multipart/form-data POST request using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java)

If the form post is not directed at a backend protected by Worklight's security framework, then you could also opt to not use adapters at all: [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: i followed the steps as mention in the first link. the following is my adater code : 

function addTwoIntegers(a,b){
 return {
  result: com.worklight.customcode.Calculator1.addTwoIntegers(a,b)
 };
}

function subtractTwoIntegers(a,b){
 var calcInstance = new com.worklight.customcode.Calculator1();
 
 return {
  result : calcInstance.subtractTwoIntegers(a,b)
 };
}
 
i am getting the following error on invoking the adapter.
"Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot call property addTwoIntegers in object [JavaPackage com.worklight.customcode.Calculator1]. It is not a function, it is \"object\".