# Multipart request with IBM MobileFirst Adapter

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, multipart

I am a newbiee to IBM Mobile First. I was trying to send a multi-part request using MobileFirst HTTP Adapter. But after googling, I came to know that it is not possible in MFP JavaScript Adapter ([constructing a multipart form request in a adapter using MobileFirst version 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814627/constructing-a-multipart-form-request-in-a-adapter-using-mobilefirst-version-6-3)). But, since, this question is not specifying anything about MFP v8.0, so it let me to again search for help on Internet, but I failed to get any working solution. So, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to create multi-part request from adapters with **WL.Server.invokeHttp()** function on adapter side?
2. If **yes**, then please guide me with the process with which I can send multi-part request from IBM server to my actual server; and if **no**, please tell the ways with which I can send multi-part request from IBM server to my actual server (since API I am hitting needs data to be in multi-part format)?

IBM **must have provided some way** to make multi-part request from Adapters, to the extent I think.

Explanations with answer will be more appreciated as it would help to take brief look into this topic.

Comment: Which MobileFirst version are  you working on ?

Comment: I am using MFP v8.0.

Comment: So you're not asking about an adapter *accepting* multi-part requests, you're asking about an adapter having code that *calls* another service that accepts multi-part requests, correct? And your adapter is (or can be) Java? I doubt you'll be able to do it from a Javascript adapter.

Comment: yes, am not asking about adaptors accepting multi-part request. Actually I want to send multipart request from adaptor itself. The flow is like this:
1. Server API requires data to be in multi-part/form-data.
2. So for this, from my javascript file, I converted all parameters to form data object using FormData() and passed that object to procedure in adapter  from my cordova application.
3. At adapter end, I assigned that variable (containing form data object) to variable named 'content' in body object before invoking http request.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to create multi-part request from adapters with WL.Server.invokeHttp() function on adapter side?

**No,  this is not possible in MFP using Javascript adapter**

However like Idan explained in  [constructing a multipart form request in a adapter using MobileFirst version 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814627/constructing-a-multipart-form-request-in-a-adapter-using-mobilefirst-version-6-3) ,  you can send multi-part data by adding the logic in your **Java adapter** code.

Refer to: [How can I make a multipart/form-data POST request using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java) " .

Comment: Thanks Kavitha for your time. But the question is asking specifically about v8.0, not any other version. I have already research on those version but I need to know about v8.0 only. Please provide your help for this version only. Thanks again

Comment: It is no different in MFP 80 as well . You need to use MFP 80 Java adapters

Comment: Thanks Vivin for your response. I would request you to please give a detailed help regarding how can I use Java Adapters regarding constructing http multipart request from adapters to actual server, retaining IBM analytics with adaptors using Java only since I am unable to get any help regarding IBM Mobile First (may be due to less support for IBM Mobile First online). Thanks again