# How to consume the fileupload restful webservice using restful template

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I am newbie to restful webservice.My requirement is to upload a multiple files.i successfully write the code for uploading multiple files in restful web service.Below is my code.

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/multipleFiles")
    public String registerWebService(@Context HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String responseStatus = SUCCESS_RESPONSE;        
        String candidateName = null;

        //checks whether there is a file upload request or not
        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
        {
            final FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            final ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            try
            {
                /*
                 * parseRequest returns a list of FileItem
                 * but in old (pre-java5) style
                 */
                final List items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);

                if (items != null)
                {
                    final Iterator iter = items.iterator();
                    while (iter.hasNext())
                    {
                        final FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                        final String itemName = item.getName();
                        final String fieldName = item.getFieldName(); 
                        final String fieldValue = item.getString();

                        if (item.isFormField())
                        {
                            candidateName = fieldValue;
                            System.out.println("Field Name: " + fieldName + ", Field Value: " + fieldValue);
                            System.out.println("Candidate Name: " + candidateName);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                final File savedFile = new File(FILE_UPLOAD_PATH + File.separator
                                         + itemName);

                                item.write(savedFile);                                
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (FileUploadException fue)
            {
                responseStatus = FAILED_RESPONSE;
                fue.printStackTrace();                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                responseStatus = FAILED_RESPONSE;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }        



        return responseStatus;
    }
```

Is it good to upload multifiles in single request?
I want to consume the above restful webservice using restful template or jersey or any other java client.
Can anybody please guide me to write the client code for consuming the above webservice?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What you exactly wants do to on client side?

Comment: i have to call the upload service argument is to multiple files and name

Comment: Consider reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java

Comment: thanks for the link.i need to send multiple files via restful template or jersey.Is it possible?