# Spring boot Multipart file upload using Client Side Java Code

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, multipart

I have written a restful web service in spring boot which receives the file.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile uploadfile) {
    System.out.println("filename: " + uploadfile.getName());
}
```

How can we **upload the file from client side java code to web service**. Instead of AJAX call or HTML page form multipart request?

The code below call the web service with JSON object. Like this I want to receive the file in above written web service.

```
void clientRequest(String server_url, JSONObject fileObj){

  try {

    URL url = new URL(server_url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(fileObj.toString().getBytes());
    os.flush();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        logger.info("output :: " + output);
    }

    conn.disconnect();

  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a `MultipartFile`, you must use the `multipart/form-data` mimetype when requesting. Instead of sending the JSON as request entity, you should construct a specific multipart-entity with a single field `file` in it.

This is how it's done: [How can I make a multipart/form-data POST request using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java])

Comment: The code given in the link is not working. I have already tired it. Most of it's methods are deprecated.

Comment: The code contains an updated answer for the 4.3 version of `http-client`.

Comment: Thanks I tired http-client 4.3 It's working earlier it wasn't working

Comment: How can we send JSONObject along with the file to web service

Comment: You can include the JSON as a second multipart form field with another field name. You'll get a second `@RequestParam` in the REST controller. Just pull that file  stream throug an `ObjectMapper`. Because you're using multipart miletype, you cant use the `@RequestBody` to get the JSON converted to a POJO. If the JSON data you want to combine with the file is really simple, consider flattening the data and include it as separate form-fields which contain the property values istead of a file...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring's `HttpEntity` along with `ByteArrayResource` to upload the file, here is an example:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes()) {
    @Override
    public String getFilename() {
        return file.getName();
    }
};
data.add("file", resource);

HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(data, requestHeaders);

final ResponseEntity<<SomeClass>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(<url>, 
        HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<SomeClass>(){});

SomeClass result = responseEntity.getBody();
```