# Java - multipart/form-data POST request using a remote file (with http:// or file:// protocols)

Tags: java, http

I followed this thread for uploading a multipart/form-data file:
[how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java).
However I couldn't find anything regarding uploading a file from remote server.
for example, lets say i have a file here:
file://serverIP/folder/subFolder/file.x
I can access the file using http as well:
http://serverIP/subFoler/file.x

this is piece my code:

```
File fileToUpload = new File("file://serverIP/folder/subFolder/file.x");
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(fullUri);
    HttpEntity multipart = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                        .addTextBody("field1", "yes", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                        .addBinaryBody("file", fileToUpload, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, fileToUpload.getName())
                        .build();
    request.setEntity(multipart);
```

after executibg I get **java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\serverIP\folder\subFolder\file.x (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect).**

Can someone help me understand what is wrong with the path and why the it converts it to file:\...?

Answer (score 0):

The number of slashes that you put after `file:` is dependent on the host(in your case remote serverIP's) os environment. For example in windows it generally works `file://` but for unix environment it is `file:///`. `new File(URI)` works only on files in local system as only those files are applicable to be accessed using the `file:` format.

On the other hand idea remains the same and that you need to download the remote file corresponding to the remote url at a tmp local path and then use that tmp file to build the http-request. You can use [FileUtils#copyURLToFile](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL,%20java.io.File))

```
File fileToUpload = new File(_some tmp path_);    
FileUtils.copyURLtoFile(remoteFileUrl, fileToUpload);
```

Also this does not changes your `http-entity` since `fileToUpload` and `fileToUpload.getName()` still remains the same

P.S.: be careful while deleting this temp File a.k.a `fileToUpload`

Comment: it's not working, I get exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"

Comment: It seems that URI scheme does not work when it comes to remote url. answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

public class Post_Remote_File {

    private static final String POST_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/post-demo/post-receiver.php";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File fileToUpload = new File("index.html");
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL("http://127.0.0.1/post-demo/index.html"), fileToUpload);
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(POST_URL);
        HttpEntity multipart = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .addTextBody("field1", "yes", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .addBinaryBody("file", fileToUpload, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, fileToUpload.getName())
                .build();
        request.setEntity(multipart);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        //int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String body = handler.handleResponse(response);
        //HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println(body);

    }
}
```

I am **using HttpComponents Core, HttpComponents Client (from [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/)), Commons Logging, Commons IO (from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/)) and [Apache HttpClient Mime](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime).** So ensure these are present in classpath before execution (thats why i pasted full code here). Below is the library explorer view for this project, or use Maven to resolve dependencies.

[image]

*The problem with this approch : `FileUtils` will download the file from specified URL, then copy to specified file (you can find index.html on the file explorer of the project) ; this may lead to problems with large file.*

Answer (score 0):

well the answer is quite stupid, but the only way it worked for me was adding file:///**/** (four back slashes), and it converted the URI to \\serverIP\folder\subFolder\file.x

Answer (score 0):

First things first: On what kind of server are you trying to access the files? Because:

> The prefix concept is used to handle root directories on UNIX platforms, and drive specifiers, root directories and UNC pathnames on Microsoft Windows platforms (From Oracle Java docs)

a bit differently.
For the hints you can take a look [there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). Next thing this line:

```
File fileToUpload = new File("file://serverIP/folder/subFolder/file.x");
```

if it is a linux server, then this should be sufficient to access the file:

```
File fileToUpload = new File("serverIP:/here_comes_your_absolute_path");
```

For "windows" server it should be something looking like the following:

```
File fileToUpload = new File("\\\\serverIP\\here\\comes\\yourpath\\file.txt")
```

P.S. my answer might be incomplete I will be glad to edit it anytime.