# Upload File in form data using Java

Tags: java, apache, http

I am trying to perform a HTTP Post Request in Java using the Apache API.

With curl the request looks like this

```
curl https://host/upload
-X POST
-H "Authorization: Bearer xxx"
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
-H "Accept: application/json"
-F "file=@{PathToImage}" -F "type=file"
```

While this work fine when running it with CURL the server returns a 500er result when running it with the following Java code

```
    final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://host/upload");
    httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxx");
    httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

    final MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    final File file = new File("c:\\tmp\\myfile.pdf");
    builder.addBinaryBody("file", file);
    builder.addTextBody("type", "file");
    final HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
    httppost.setEntity(entity);
    final HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    httpclient.close();
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: try with addPartBody instead of addBinaryBody.

Comment: try to remove ```httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");```

Comment: @Paul, don't you have access to the called server logs? Did you check the response body for potential error details? You can also use a proxy like Fiddler and compare the requests generated from CURL vs. from Java...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java) question is similar. But I believe the answer is changing your addBinary to addPart.

```
final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://host/upload");
httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxx");
httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

final MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
final File file = new File("c:\\tmp\\myfile.pdf");
builder.addPart("file", new FileBody(file));
builder.addTextBody("type", "file");
final HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
httppost.setEntity(entity);
final HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
httpclient.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try syntax as [baeldung multipart upload article](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-multipart-upload) suggest:

```
String textFileName = "c:\\tmp\\myfile.pdf";
final File file = new File(textFileName);
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
builder.addBinaryBody("file", file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, textFileName);
builder.addTextBody("type", "file", ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);
```

> create a multipart entity is to use the addBinaryBody and AddTextBody methods. These methods work for uploading text, files, character arrays, and InputStream objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunatelly I am still getting a 500er response.

Comment: @Paul it may be related to missing User-Agent, try adding `httppost.addHeader("User-Agent", "Any String will do");`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this instead

```
        //import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((user + ":" + psw).getBytes("UTF-8"));

        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("Basic %s", encoding));
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Java client");

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(val);
```