# IBM MobileFirst Adapter accepting Multipart request

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mfp

I am a newbie to IBM MobileFirst, I am trying to upload an image using Multipart. Whenever I try to call the API to upload image I get an error in the Postman saying 415 content not found or 500 server error. So I just wanted to know does IBM mobile first java adapter accepts **multi-part requests**?

I have attached the Java code used , but none of these are working:

1)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public @ResponseBody
            String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) 
            {
                return null;
            
            }
```

2. tried this also :

   ```
      @POST
      @Path("/upload")
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @OAuthSecurity(enabled=false)
      public ResponseEntity<?> upload(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile files) {
                log.info("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                return null;
   ```

   }
3. ```
     @POST
     @Path("/addEmployeeAttachment")
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
     @OAuthSecurity(enabled=false)
     public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> addEmployeeAttachment(     
             @RequestParam(required = false, value = "attachmentFile") MultipartFile attachmentFile) {

         log.info("xxxxxxxxxx");
         return null;

     }
   ```

Comment: Please elaborate on when do you see the 415 and when do you see the 500 error code.A 500 HTTP code is typically accompanied by an error in the server log. Share the server log when the 500 code is seen

Answer (score 0):

With reference to IBM Mobile first development reference document https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/c_restapi_oview.html

We can use `Deploy (POST)` for Deploys a multipart compressed file.

JSON example:-

```
{
  "ok" : false,
  "productVersion" : "8.0",
  "transaction" : {
    "appServerId" : "Tomcat",
    "description" : {
      "name" : "myname",
      "type" : "mytype",
    },
    "errors" : [
      {
        "details" : "An internal error occured.",
      },
      ...
    ],
    "id" : 1,
    "project" : {
      "name" : "myproject",
    },
    "status" : "FAILURE",
    "timeCreated" : "2014-04-13T00:18:36.979Z",
    "timeUpdated" : "2014-04-14T00:18:36.979Z",
    "type" : "UPLOAD_ARTIFACT",
    "userName" : "demouser",
  },
}
```

Standard Error code:-

```
Errors 400 No deployable data is provided. 403 The user is not
authorized to call this service. 404 The corresponding runtime is not
found or not running. 500 An internal error occurred.
```

Could you pleas refer [How can I make a multipart/form-data POST request using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java) as well.

I hope it will help you to understand more about multipart API.